# Upgrading to Airflow 2, no module named 'airflow.hooks.base'

Tags: airflow

We're upgrading to Airflow 2 so I've changed the hooks import from:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
```

to

```
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook
```

and now I'm getting this error:

> {plugins_manager.py:225} ERROR - No module named 'airflow.hooks.base'

Here are the docs for this change, but I don't see any other required changes to get airflow.hooks.base to work: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a17db7883044889b2b2001cefc41a8960359a23f/UPDATING.md#changes-to-import-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are running on Airflow 2.0.

You can check which version you are running with the [version command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#version).

```sh
airflow version
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm doing Airflow 1.10.15 which is the bridge version to Airflow 2. Maybe the bridge  version doesn't support this just Airflow 2?

Comment: The bridge version still uses pre 2.0 syntax. The changes to import path is only valid in 2.0.